# Unable to brew upgrade Python in Mojave

Tags: python, homebrew, permission-denied, macos-mojave

I ran `brew outdated` in macOS Mojave 10.14.2 and determined that `python` and `python@2` were outdated. When I ran `brew upgrade` it failed for both. For example for `python@2`:

```
==> Upgrading python@2 
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/python@2-2.7.15_2.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring python@2-2.7.15_2.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Error: An unexpected error occurred during the `brew link` step
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
```

I ran `brew doctor` and it recommends to `brew link` but this still fails with the same permission error:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_2... Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514084/how-to-fix-brew-doctor-errors-on-mac-osx-10-9-unlinked-kegs-in-cellar-and-hom) recommends to grant privileges to the parent directory, but I want to understand why this happens and find a solution for learning.

Comment: What happens when you run `brew upgrade` with `sudo`?

Comment: I suppose that would work - however the same brew upgrade worked in my other mac running an older High Sierra.

Comment: What permissions does your other mac has for that folder?

Comment: `ls -l /usr/local/Frameworks` returns `drwxr-xr-x  6`.

Comment: Regarding the use of `sudo` with `brew` commands I got the following error: `Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3228). I had to `sudo mkdir /usr/local/Frameworks` to create the missing directory first, then `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` since `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local` no longer works in Mojave - and High Sierra before that, according to the post. I was able to `brew link python` and `brew link python@2` after that.

Comment: Yesterday, I was able to reinstall Python in Mojave running these commands before _brew_: `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/Frameworks` and then `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Frameworks`.